# Nexted styled component nodes and their children not appearing in react testing library DOM

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[Here is what the DOM should look like via the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNtoZ.jpg)

[This is the DOM output from screen.debug()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87svV.jpg)

```
 {Object.keys(lastWeekDays).map((day) => (
    <React.Fragment key={day}>
      <Day key={day}>{day}</Day>
      {getHourlyIntervalsPerDay(2, day).map((interval) => (
        <Hour key={`${day}-${Object.keys(interval)[0]}`}>
          <Cell
            key={`${day}-${Object.keys(interval)[0]}-hour1`}
            props={
              getSplitInterval(interval[Object.keys(interval)[0]].UTC[0])[0]
            }
          />
          <Cell
            key={`${day}-${Object.keys(interval)[0]}-hour2`}
            props={
              getSplitInterval(interval[Object.keys(interval)[0]].UTC[0])[1]
            }
          />
        </Hour>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
```

There are a lot of helper functions I'm using but basically its a table with 24 1 hour intervals over 7 days.

I've tried increasing the character count limit of debug() but it doesn't expand the DOM at all.

Comment: When I try to render Hour it doesnt show its children either. Interestingly enough, if I specifically render the entire Table component at the top  of the testing suite and debug, I see all the cells in the DOM. However if I wrap that Table render in a test block, I go back to the cells not being visible (like the second picture above). I still have no idea whats going on

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)